# Putting a submersible well pump on top of another well pump

Tags: well

So, my situation is, my submersible well pump is dead. My well is about 100' deep and it is 4" wide and the casing is steel. The professionals I've hired to remove and replace the pump have given up and one gave me an estimate for a new well and the other (he doesn't drill wells) gave me the number for another company that does drill wells. The company I was refered to  is now saying that they want to try and pull the pump out, and they are saying that worst case scenario that they will pull until something breaks, cut off the pipe to the old pump as much as they can and just put a new pump on top of the old pump. One of the professionals that I talked to refered to this as a "chop and drop".

Does that negatively affect the life of the well?

Would I be better off just drilling a new well?

Comment: The old pump should not affect the well, but will depend on how far down it will drop.  If it gets struck half way up, then your 100 ft well is about the same as a 50 ft well for draw down.

Comment: New well is not cheap, you will be looking at 5 to 15 thousand.  Usually try everything else first.

Comment: Generally there are 3 things attached to the pump.  First is the outlet pipe, second is the wiring, third there is usually a retrieval cable.  Most often the pump is pulled up via the pipe.  Failing that, the cable should be used as a backup.  It's likely not effective to try to pull up by the wiring though.  Why are these people unable to remove the old pump?

Comment: It was made in the 60's and is probably stuck due to corrosion.

Comment: The first company that came put 16 gallons of muriatic acid down the well (two applications of eight gallons over the course of two days).

Answer (score 1):

I would try hammering it down.  A stuck pump may be bound with rust and sediment pulling up may bind it tighter.
Making a lead slug 10-20 lbs 1/2 the diameter or enough to allow to slide by the electrical and pipe connected with a rope and drop it in then hammer it down to help break it loose, sometimes going back and forth with a stuck item can free it up. If worried about lead use steel, I would give that a try prior to chopping because the materials left in there electrical and pipe may not be a problem with the water but the new pump will need to be a smaller diameter to make it past the pipe.